# setInterval with loop time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
setInterval(function(){}, 200)
```

this code run the function each 200 miliseconds, how do I do it if I only want the function to be ran 10 times.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use a counter which increments each time the callback gets executed, and when it reaches your desired number of executions, use `clearInterval()` to kill the timer:

```
var counter = 0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    // do your thing

    counter++;
    if(counter === 10) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 200);
```

Comment: @JeffreySweeney http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Comment: No, but jslint will accept `window.setInterval`. jslint will not accept the lack of space between the `function` keyword and the `()`, and other stuff, but that is another discussion altogether. jslint will not accept `++` and `--`, but we're here to help OP and not "hurt his feelings" :)

Comment: I meant that those are actual bad practices. ++ and so on is just some guy's opinion.

Answer (score 8):

```
(function(){
var i = 10;
    (function k(){

        // your code here            

        if( --i ) {
        setTimeout( k, 200 );
        }

    })()
})()
```

Comment: +1 for using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.  I would probably go with `var i = 10` and `if (i--)`, but that's just me :-)

Answer (score 5):

if you want it to run for 10 times and the time it should run is every 200 miliseconds then 200X10 = 2000

```
var interval = setInterval(yourfunction, 200);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval)
}, 2000);
```

but it only runs 9 times so we must add more 200 miliseconds

```
var interval = setInterval(yourfunction, 200);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval)
}, 2200);
```

or you could run it before the setInterval

```
yourfunction();
var interval = setInterval(yourfunction, 200);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: i know its not safe but, the thing is the idea behind the code not how its done
sorry my bad english

Comment: I suggest not taking the alarming comment above not too seriously, but generally passing a function is preferred. Worth nothing that passing by string is *different behaviour*  (i.e. it looks for the function in the global scope) and all that's supported in older browsers.

Comment: I like this solution. The only thing you should provide for the clear is variable for the times of execution, and pass the multiply as a second parameter to the `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Reusable approach with options **`number of loop`** and **`delay time`** and utilize **`callback`** function

```js
const loopInterval = ( callBack, numberOfLoop, delay ) => {  
  let counter = 0;
  let i = setInterval( ()=> {
      callBack([counter, numberOfLoop]);
      counter++;
      if(counter === numberOfLoop ) clearInterval(i);
  }, delay);
}

const runThisFunctionAsCallBack = ( x ) => console.log(`Do something here...  Loop # ${x}` )

loopInterval( runThisFunctionAsCallBack, 4, 500 )
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to JavaScripter199's (the use of a for loop) approach but with the included setInterval function. See below:

```
 for (let runner = 0; runner < 10; runner++) {
      setInterval(() => {

            //Some code logic of yours.

        }
      }, 200 //run every 200 milliseconds);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a for loop instead, much easier:

Just try this code.

```
for (counter=0; counter<0; counter++) {}
```

Comment: it's not complete answer

Comment: This has a couple of issues, the `counter` is never initialized and this doesn't answer the question of how to do it within a timed delay.

Comment: When time allows you should edit the answer to include the setInterval function.