# javascript setInterval function inside loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval

I'm attempting to launch severals setInterval functions "at once".
I've got a for loop which call a function indexed, which contains the setInterval.

I've looked for answer both here:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
and here:
[setInterval with loop time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421998/setinterval-with-loop-time)

but i'm still struggling with no success...

I've checked tab and tab2, both works if I read them with console.log outside of the setInterval function

here is my code :

```
var tab = <?php echo json_encode($matrice); ?>;
var tab2 = new Array();

var funcs = [];

var countDownAction = new Array();

function countDown(i)
{
    countDownAction[i] = setInterval(function(i)
    {
        // some actions

    }, 1000);  
}


for(var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
{
    tab2[i] = [];

    tab2[i]['hours'] = tab[i]['hours'];
    tab2[i]['minutes'] = tab[i]['minutes'];
    tab2[i]['seconds'] = tab[i]['seconds'];

    funcs[i] = countDown.bind(this, i);
}

for(var j = 0; j < tab.length; j++)
{
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Comment: Does your `// some actions` depend on variable `i`?

Comment: yes, those actions depend on variable i

Comment: You're passing a function to `setinterval` which takes a parameter `i`, but `setInterval` passes no parameter to its callback, so `i` will be undefined.

Comment: Try `setInterval(function ()` ...

Comment: "*but i'm still struggling with no success...*" Define *success* in your eyes. What is suppose to happen vs. what is currently (not) happening?

Answer (score 2):

The function inside `setInterval` is called without any arguments.  Thus, `i` inside the function's body will be undefined.

Consider rewriting `countDown` function as follows:

```
function countDown(i)
{
    countDownAction[i] = setInterval(function()
    {
        // some actions

    }, 1000);  
}
```

This way, the body of the function has access to `i` in the outer scope.

To clear the timers, say 3.5 seconds later, you can do the following:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    for (var k = 0; k < tab.length; k++) {
        clearInterval(countDownAction[k]);
    }
}, 3500);
```

Comment: it may sounds stupid, but I'm not able to clear those multiples setInterval with a function called the same way I've called those setInterval functions...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use global variable for countDownAction , can you try the following instead.

```
window.countDownAction = window.countDownAction || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the loop is so fast , so the setInterval function get the last value of i variable. 
we need to set i value directly in the interval by using external function like this :

```js
var interval_Array = new Array();

for(var i; i<= number ;i++){
    var newinterval = (i+1) * 1000; //Place any process according to your time
    external_function(i,newinterval);
};

function external_function(this_i,this_interval){
    interval_Array[i]=setInterval(function(){
      //your script that contains i variable
    },this_interval);
};
```